# How to access controller items in view when created programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've just managed to make a view completely programmatically (no interface builder). But now I'm wondering how I access the different elements such as a UILabel or UISwitch etc.. In IB I'd just connect them up to their respective outlets / ibactions. How do I do it when I've created the view from code?

Answer (score 1):

Is your view a custom class, or have you just created a UIView and added subviews to it?

If you wrote a custom view class, you can make properties to refer to all these things. Then you can do `yourView.aSwitch` (or whatever your property is called) to refer to them from the controller.

If you just created a UIView and added subviews, there are two things you can do. The best option is, at the place where you're creating the switch (or whatever), keep a reference to it around, perhaps in an instance variable of your controller class. Thus you might do

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithRect:aRect];
UISwitch *switch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
[aView addSubview:switch];
// your variable 'switch' is a reference to the switch. 
// Assign it to an instance variable of your controller class here.
```

The other way you can do it (and this one isn't really recommended) is to iterate through the subviews of your view until you find the one you want. The `subviews` property of UIView gives you an array of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you created them in code, you can keep a reference to the objects your create. For instance by making a property (nonatomic, retain usually) and setting it when you create the object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you created the views contents programatically too? If so, all you need to do is keeping a reference to each element. Once you create a new UI element, just assign it to some prepared property, is the programmatic substitute for connecting elements in IB to instance variables / properties.